# Mixing active and static modes in Processing

Tags: processing

Making a space invaders knock off game. My code will not compile as I get the error message "It looks like you're mixing 'active' and 'static' modes", but I can not see where I am mixing them. Can someone please take a look at my code?

```java
final  int  SCREENX=400;  
final  int  SCREENY=400;  
final  int  GAP=10;  
final  int  ALIEN_ALIVE=0;  
final  int  ALIEN_DEAD=6;  
final  int  FORWARD=0;  
final  int  BACKWARD=1; 
final int MARGIN=30;

Alien  theAliens[]; 
Bullet bullets[];
Player thePlayer;

void  setup() {  
  PImage  normalImg, explodeImg;
  size(SCREENX, SCREENY);  
  normalImg =loadImage("invader.GIF");  
  explodeImg =loadImage("exploding.GIF");
  theAliens  =  new  Alien[10];
  bullets = new Bullet[20];  
  init_aliens(theAliens, normalImg, explodeImg);
  thePlayer  =  new  Player(SCREENY- 50);
}  

void  init_aliens(Alien  baddies[], PImage  okImg, PImage  
exImg) {  
  for (int  i=0;  i<baddies.length;  i++) {  
    //  This  is  buggy,  what  is  the  problem?  
    baddies[i]  =  new  Alien(i*(okImg.width+GAP), 0, okImg, 
    exImg);
  }
}

void init_bullets() {
  for (int i = 0; i < bullets.size(); i++) {
    Bullet b = (Bullet) bullets.get(i);
    b.move();
    b.draw();
  }
}

void shoot() {
  if (mousePressed)
    Player.shoot();
}

void  draw() {    
  background(0);
  thePlayer.draw(); 
  thePlayer.move(mouseX);
  draw_bullets(myBullets);  
  for (int  i=0;  i<theAliens.length;  i++) {  
    theAliens[i].move();  
    theAliens[i].draw();

    if (random(0, 500)<1)
      theAliens[i].die();
  }
}

////// Player Class //////
Player() {        ///** When I get the error, this line is highlighted**///
  this.x = width/2;
  this.y = height-50;
  this.timeLastShot = 0;
  this.coolDown = 200;
  colour playColour= color(50);

  void draw() {
    fill(playerColour);
    rect(this.x, this.y, 30, 30);
  }

  void move(int x) {
    if (x>SCREENX-50) 
      xpos= SCREENX-50;
    else xpos=x;
  }
    void shoot() {
      if (millis() - timeLastShot > coolDown) {
        Bullet bullet = new Bullet(this.x+12.5, this.y, -5);
        bullets.add(bullet);
        timeLastShot = millis();
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What language is this? And please edit your question to include the complete (and unedited) error log, while pointing out where in the posted source the errors are (the error messages do have source file name and line numbers).

Comment: It's processing. It's based on Java. I had it in my 'tags'. I have edited my question.

Comment: Also, that is the error message I am getting, I did not edit it.@JoachimPileborg

Answer (score 3):

Your *Player* class is badly written. It should be:

```
class Player {

Player () {
//constructor
}

void functionOfSorts () {

} // Never forget to enclose functions with curly brackets!

}
```

...As opposed to what you wrote:

```
Player() { 
//yadayada
}
```